# What is the size of MINI_KIND in megabytes in android

Tags: android, bitmap, size, thumbnails, megabyte

What is the size of `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND` in megabytes in android? The dimension of the bitmap is said to be `MINI_KIND: 512 x 384`.

In case you need to know: My use case is the thumbnail of a video using ThumbnailUtils.

Comment: While this won't answer the question it shows an upper limit: when you upload video thumbnails to Youtube, Google asks that you keep it under 2MB https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431?hl=en-GB. I imagine the one in your question is much smaller than that.

Comment: Someone else needs to confirm this, but if the numbers here are pixels, we may be talking about 30kb JPEG.

Comment: But to be safe you should assume 100KB, the reason I say 100 is because of resolution. The higher the resolution to more space it will take. **This is not the answer to your question.** but you can verify my statement about 100kb: take a very large image and open it in your image viewer on your computer (on my mac I use Preview), then if you try to edit the picture and resize it to 512x384, it should come to something less than 100KB and maybe as small as 30KB depending on resolution. I good answer should have reference. And so this is not your "good" answer.